# Ignoring part of text between command

Tags: comments

I'm trying to write a custom class similar to exam but I want to add the following fonctionality : a question can be hidden depending on some boolean value. When using an environment, it works, but I would like to provide a \question command in the same fashion as exam does.
Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\newcounter{question}
\newif\ifvisible \visibletrue
\NewEnviron{Question}
{%
    \refstepcounter{question}%
    \ifvisible%
        \list{\textbf{\arabic{question}.~}}{\leftmargin=.8cm}\item%
        \BODY
        \endlist
    \fi%
}

\newif\ifinsideQuestion \insideQuestionfalse
\newcommand{\question}{
    \ifinsideQuestion
        \end{Question}
    \fi
    \begin{Question}
    \insideQuestiontrue
}

\newenvironment{exercice}{}{
    \ifinsideQuestion
        \end{Question}
    \fi
}


\begin{document}

% Work
\begin{exercice}
    \begin{Question}
        Question 1
    \end{Question}
    \visiblefalse
    \begin{Question}
        Question 2
    \end{Question}
\end{exercice}
\visibletrue

% Error
\begin{exercice}
    \question Question 1
    \visiblefalse
    \question Question 2
\end{exercice}
\end{document}
```

This doesn't work because environ seems to look for the end of the environment on the first \question but doesn't expand the second question so never find it.

Comment: You might define \question first and have the Question environment expand \question rather than the other way around.  \end{exercise} when \insidequestiontrue will always produce an error.

Comment: I tried to do something similar, but I didn't manage to find a way such that the first question open a comment environment if visible is fase, and the second question close this comment environment. When the first one open the comment, it again seems to ignore everything after.

Comment: Comment environment?  BTW, you might want to handle the indentation directly using \leftskip rather than use a list environment.

Comment: The comment environment was for a way to ignore everything between the two \question command. I didn't find another way to activate some kind of ignore flag until next question is found. I tried to use delimited macro, using \question as a begin and an end delimiter, but after stopping on the second \question, latex doesn't proceed it. This implies that I should write two \question, the first one for closing the macro, the second on for starting the next question. But this is not exactly what I want...

Comment: An environment needs a \begin{comment} and \end{comment} (which is actually implemented using macros \comment and \endcomment).  One could implement this using \NewEnviron{comment}{}.